# No me cargan las imágenes de mi web

Tags: html5, web, apache, imagen, ftp

Despúes de estar todo el fin de semana para lograr configurar dominio, vesta, etc etc y muchos dolores de cabeza ( es mi primer dominio subido por ftp ). Logro conseguirlo casi todo pero ahora no me cargan las imágenes y no sé ni por qué, pone que no se puede cargar el archivo. Les dejo la página para que vean ustedes el directorio y demás -> todoprogramasgratis.es .

Las imágenes están dentro de public_html -> imagenes/logos o ccleaner/imagenes.

Si utilizo el src dominio/imagenes/logos o cclenaer/imagenes, me funcionó una vez, pero ha vuelto a decir que no puede cargar los archivos, aunque si me meto desde indexof a las imágenes me da un error 404 :/, pero poniendo el dominio mas la ubicación si se me muestra (la imagen) no la imagen en sus sitios de la web. Si alguien sabe que estoy haciendo mal... rogaría que me abran los ojos.

Actualizo: Algunas veces si se me muestran las imágenes que cojo desde una ruta absoluta ej-> dominio.es/imagenes/logos/logo_rojo.png. Pero esto solo dura un rato de nada, luego deja de cargar, debería subirlas a otro servidor o cómo debo hacer?

Answer (score 1):

No debes usar espacios para nombrar carpetas o archivos, usa el "_" de preferencia: Ejemplo: /nombre_carpeta/nombre_de_mi_imagen.jpg

El archivo se te va a mostrar porque el navegador "entiende" los espacios en blanco, sin embargo en html, debe añadir un carácter especial para indicar que hay un espacio en blanco.

La mejor solución es que pueda renombrar tu archivo o carpeta.

Comment: Buenas, gracias por la respuesta, no hay espacios en ningun sitio, un ejemplo serio /imagenes/Logos/LogoRojo.png. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Vale chicos, al ver que no me cargaba poniendo las rutas que pusiera, he decido subir las fotos a otro servidor y cargar las imágenes desde la ruta de ese servidor, por si alguien ha hecho lo mismo que yo ya tiene una solución.